# How to do complex form validation in Symfony2?

Tags: php, forms, validation, symfony

I have an accounting app in Symfony 2.7.x.

When creating a new transaction, the total amount in the transaction may be split across multiple categories but I need to validate that the total of the category amounts is not greater than the total of the transaction.

ie- **Transaction:**

Payee: Exxon

Amount: $100.00

**Categories:**

---

Name: Snacks

Amount: $45.00

---

Name: Gasoline

Amount: $55.00

Each category is a separate entity in the database as well.

So if the user changed Gasoline to $65.00, the form should fail validation.

I've researched Symfony 2 form validation but everything I find seems to revolve around Constraint Annotations on single properties of an object and not across multiple entities.

I'm assuming I need to set up a validation service, but I'm struggling with how to set it up and to get it to trigger on the appropriate form.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the [Expression](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Expression.html) validation constraint to spare a few lines of code. It can be as easy to validate as:

YML:

```
AppBundle\Entity\Transaction:
constraints:
    - Expression:
        expression: "this.getAmount() >= this.getCategorySum()"
        message: "Amount should be greater then or equal to the sum of amounts."
```

Or with annotations:

```
/**
 * @Assert\Expression(
 *     "this.getAmount() >= this.getCategorySum()",
 *     message="Amount should be greater then or equal to the sum of amounts."
 * )
 */
 class Transaction{
   ...
   public function getCategorySum(){
   ...
```

Where the getCategorySum() method of the Transaction object would return the sum of amounts of the categories.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, yes, all the primitive `validators` do not work.
You need a to write a `custom callback`.
From symfony documentation [CallBack](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Callback.html):

> Callback
>
> The purpose of the Callback constraint is to create completely custom validation rules and to assign any
>   validation errors to specific fields on your object. If you're using
>   validation with forms, this means that you can make these custom
>   errors display next to a specific field, instead of simply at the top
>   of your form.

So, in your case it would be as following:

```
class Transaction
{
    //...
    private $amount;
    //...

    /**
     * @Assert\Callback
     */
    public function validate(ExecutionContextInterface $context)
    {
        // ...
        //Get your total category price here.
        $totalCategoryPrice = ...;
        if($this->amount<$totalCategoryPrice)
        {
            $context->buildViolation('Total amount can not be greater than the total amount of each category.')
            ->atPath('amount')
            ->addViolation();
        }

    }
}
```